# Will Unity interfere with gnome-shell?

Tags: unity, 11.10, gnome

Do you think having Unity would mess with shell?

I ask this because I already have had the issue of the unity global menu appearing behind the gnome panel.

I have resolved it, however do you think that there could possibly be other bugs caused by presence of both DE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using 11.10, the answer is

## NO.

The reason why is extremely complex, but to simplify it, removing `Unity` will break your system upgrades, and make it extremely difficult to get security updates for some parts of the Ubuntu Desktop.