# Upgrade 12.10(gnome installer) to 13.04(gnome)

Tags: 12.10, gnome, upgrade, 13.04

I have installed clean Ubuntu with gnome desktop environment (This was installer only with gnome so no unity and not upgraded from unity to gnome). And I'm very happy with it, but there is a system massage that tells me there is an update to 13.04.

Ok thats cool, but if I press upgrade will it upgrade everything OK, and keep my gnome? Or it will upgrade and install Unity and mix up my whole installation.

I've read that its not very good to have both gnome and unity or to "upgrade" from one to another. It's always better to just clean install the one you like.

So my question is: If I upgrade my Ubuntu 12.10-gnome will it keep it (the gnome) or it will install unity and its going to be a big mess...?

Thanks

Comment: Depends on what exact packages you have installed. I hope you realize that "installer only with gnome" is such a vague definition of what's in place, that I'd recommend against upgrading.

Comment: In which case, Stuci needs to downgrade (clean install) to Ubuntu LTS for the extra support. Staying on 12.10 isn't the BEST idea.

So I recommended upgrading anyway to see what happens, if everything breaks, that's fine, downgrade anyway.

Comment: Ah, yes it probably [will break](http://askubuntu.com/questions/67756/will-unity-interfere-with-gnome-shell?rq=1) oh well, might as well see what happens. You can also switch to a login terminal (`Ctrl` + `Alt` + `F1`) and then use `ubuntu-bug packagename` (replacing `packagename` with the relevant package) to bug report everything that breaks :D

Or, to increase stability, just `sudo apt-get install unity`, you don't have to use it, it's just there for packages to 'depend' on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to upgrade Ubuntu and gnome without breaking existing settings?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/210583/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-and-gnome-without-breaking-existing-settings)

Answer (score -1):

Updates generally are a big mess. 
Try pressing upgrade, it SHOULD just upgrade all your current packages to the 13.04 versions (including GNOME), it shouldn't install Unity unless if something depends on it.

If that doesn't work, downgrade to Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS (clean install) and add the [GNOME 3 PPA](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/gnome3) (not recommended but will get you the most up-to-date GNOME 3 experience on Ubuntu LTS).

If you think a PPA is too risky, just use the command `sudo apt-get install gnome-shell` to get the repository version of GNOME 3.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but im not sure for this downgrading story. I'm new to Linux/Ubuntu and I have just made my system work, let's say good enough. So any more time spended in adjusting my system will be a problem to me :)

So I will just wait a little bit and we shall see what happens next :P

Comment: (Sorry for the late reply) I still strongly recommend upgrading to 13.04 because it is the most recent interim version. If you wanted to stick to something for a while you should've got Ubuntu LTS sorry. Just upgrade and even if it installs Unity, you can always 'sudo apt-get remove unity' and add the PPA I mentioned above.